# iOS User Login Interface Library for Rails api backend

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I am looking for a library which provides user login/signup UI for my iPhone/iPad app to connect with backend api.

I use devise_token_auth gem on Rails api side, but I guess I can handle auth part by coding, I am just looking for a handy UI library like ParseUI so I don't need to make it by myself.

I tried to search using github and http://cocoapods.wantedly.com/, but no luck yet.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a library with built in Devise support for iOS: https://github.com/netguru/devise-ios

Comment: Thanks!  Does it work with devise_token_auth gem?  I plan to make Android app in the future, so I am worried if I use devise-ios-rails on Rails for this iOS library, it will be locked with iOS and Rails only.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with devise_token_auth, but this library makes use of the standard devise gem. Anything you do client side on iOS shouldn't have any effect on a future Android implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

It turned out Cocoa Controls was the best for this porpose. 
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=login